# How do you completely hide an element from a user based on their ASP.NET Identity Role?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

Goal: Hide certain elements like page links from users based on their role in ASP.NET Identity.

What I have tried: `[Authorize(Roles = IdentityHelper.Administrator)]`

(This does restrict access to certain elements if you put the annotation over them, like pages, but it doesn't hide the element itself. I want it to do both.) Its not entirely critical that I hide these elements from the user since they're already restricted, but it would make my website look better to the users.

(IdentityHelper is just a helper class that sets up all the details about the administrator role)

Code Example:

```cs
//Restricts access, which is good, but does not completely hide elements from user.
[Authorize(Roles = IdentityHelper.Administrator)] 
public  async Task <IActionResult> Edit(int id)
{
    //get pixel art with corrosponding id
    PixelArt p =  await PixelDBManager.GetSinglePixelAsync(id, _context);

    //pass pixel art to view
    return View(p);
}
```

Should I perhaps switch to Claims or Policy based identity instead of Roles or can I stick with Roles to solve this particular problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `User.IsInRole()` in your Razor template.

```html
@if(User.IsInRole(IdentityHelper.Administrator))
{
    <h1>I'm an administrator</h1>
}
```

Comment: Tested this solution with both anonymous users, and logged in users who are not administrators, works perfectly, thank you!